# Getting values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the value out of an array in PHP.

The value of $v when displayed with print_r($v) is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([name] => BLARGH ) 
        [1] => Array ( [name] => TEMP CATEGORY ) 
       )
```

I'm trying to iterate over this and pull out the value of the name key as follows:

```
foreach($v as $category) {
 echo  $category->name; 
}
```

The echo returns no value. Further, if I add a print_r($category) to the loop I get a return of

```
Array ( [name] => TEMP CATEGORY )
```

How do I get the name value out of the array?

Comment: Did you do any research at all regarding accessing values of arrays?

Comment: @OP You can also type cast an array to an object if you wish to retain the -> operation. IE foreach ($v as $category) { $category = (object)$category; echo $category->name; } For this small of a demonstration its a little overkill, but some like to retain the -> method rather than ['name'] clutter. Example: http://ideone.com/Nxoejf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside your foreach loop do `$category['name']`

Answer (score 2):

This is an array, not an object. Use array notation:

```
echo $category['name'];
```

See here: http://3v4l.org/gPL27

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($v as $category) {
   echo  $category['name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($v as $category) {

   echo  $category['name']; 

}
```

what you did wrong:

in this case:

```
$catagory->name
```

`$category` would need to be an object, not an array

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
foreach($v as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: This would echo `1` and `Array`.

Comment: you're right, i read too fast and didn't see it was multidimensional